# I want to print in python a nested loop from 1 to 10 as shown 10 rows and 10 columns

Tags: python

this is how is supposed to look like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit misleading, but would this work?

```
for _ in range(10):
    print(list(range(1, 11)))
```

or this?

```
for _ in range(10):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{i},", end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(str(i)+", ",end="")
    print("")

>>> 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(1, 11):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        print(j, end="")
        print(",", end="")
    print()
```